# What is the command line in Puppy Linux that is equivalent to apt-get commands?

Tags: apt, puppy-linux

I have difficulties of installing apps in puppy linux,

I realise that `apt-get`, `yum` don't work in puppy linux,

what is the correct command in puppy linux that is equivalent to `apt-get` or `yum`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install packages in Puppy Linux, use the `Puppy Package Manager` (`ppm` on the command line) or the `quickpet` tool.

Comment: Thank you. I find the puppy package manager & quickpet are rather limited in the likes of slacko puppy.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official web site's wiki](https://puppylinux.org/wikka/software), it uses [Puppy Package Manager](https://puppylinux.org/wikka/ppm), the verb on the command-line for which is `ppm`.

Comment: Thank you, I should have read the official wiki...!

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get` will not work you have to use
`pkg -i update` and then `pkg -get PACKAGENAME` and then `pkg -i PACKAGENAME`

Answer (score 0):

Hey to update puppy linux you have to click on `Menu > Setup > Puppy Updates` which is equivalent to `apt-get update` .... And yes you can install different packages using **Puppy Package Manager**